# PlayWright - Getting the value of element <dd> inside <div>

Tags: node.js, playwright-typescript

I have below structure.:

```
<div class="aClassName">
   <dl>
      <dt>Employee Name</dt>
      <dd data-testid="employee1">Sam</dd>
   </dl>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the values of dd.

```
const element = page.getByTestId(employee1).innerText();
await expect(element).toEqual('Sam');
```

and

```
const element = page.getByTestId(employee1).textContent();
await expect(element).toEqual('Sam');
```

The element is found, but the text is not being returned.

```
Error: expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

Expected: "Sam"
Received: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is solved. I fixed it with moving the await:

```
const element = await page.getByTestId(employee1).innerText();
expect(element).toEqual('Sam');
```